# hide div while the page is loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two "ul" list. With javascript a remove childrens from the second list and add inside the first ul list. But while the page is loading the second menu appears unstyled. see [here](http://envato.d.pr/8zAW/1F7TtfUa) and the [web](http://www.codetocode-developments.com/quins/)

Here is the code. #main-menu and #section menu are the ul lists:

```
//dinamyc main menu
    if( $('body').hasClass('page-template-templateshome-page-php') ){
        $('#section_menu').children().each(function(i, e){
            var firstLi = '#' + $('.navbar').next().attr("id");
            $('.home .menu-item-home a').removeClass('external').attr( "href", firstLi );

            if($('#main-menu div ul li').is($(e).insertAfter('#main-menu ul li:eq(0)'))){
                $(e).insertAfter('#main-menu ul:eq(0)');
            }

            $('#section_menu').css('display','none');

        });
    }else{
        $('#section_menu ').children().remove();
        $('#section_menu').remove();
    }
```

CSS:

```
#section_menu { display:none; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div id="hidden-during-page-load">Loading...</div>

$(window).load(function(){
  // this will ensure that all content has loaded before the div is shown
  $("#hidden-during-page-load").show();
});

#hidden-during-page-load {
    display:none;   
}
```

Comment: I think you should change `#hidden-during-page-load` to a class so that the class can be used on multiple objects, but now I don't feel the need to post an answer with external CSS, +1

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
<div id="mydiv" style="disply:none">somedata</div>
```

then make that div whenever you want. If you want to show it in page load,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 //after executing some functions
  $("#mydiv").show()
  });
```

Comment: @Genethic didnt it hide?

Comment: not, it doesn`t work. I have add a link to the page in the question

Comment: did you added this style="disply:none" in your parent tag?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried puting a breakpoint inside your each function?
That'd confirm that that process is causing the glitch. (or you can also add a small delay in it)
Put the breakpoint and do what you've been doing so far, if the menu remains that way until you let it continue, it means you need to change your logic: Hide the menu during processing and only show it when the process is complete.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a css rule to hide the second list for example:

```
.hidden-list {
    visibility: hidden
}
```

If after loading you want to see the second list, just listen to the `ready` event and remove the class.

```
$(document).ready( function($) {
    $('ul').removeClass('hidden-list'))
    // Do something else if needed
});
```